# hibernate and DB triggers

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate and pre-insert triggers in database. Let me explain the scenario.
I have two tables say A and B. In both the tables Primary keys are inserted through pre-insert triggers. Primary key from A is foreign key in B. So when I insert into these tables the foreign key column in B should get populated with triggered value of A (the primary key value). But its not happening as I am expecting. Primary keys in both tables are inserted properly but the foreign key column keeps getting value 0 instead of the triggered value which it should actually get.
Table have one-to-many relationship.

The two tables are like -

```
class Employee {
   private int RECORDID;
   @OneToMany(cascade=cascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="MASTERRECORDID" , referencedColumnName="RECORDID")
   private Collection<EmployeeDetails> employeeDetails = new ArrayList<EmployeeDetails>();
}

class EmployeeDetails{
   private int RECORDID;
   private int MASTERRECORDID;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't support primary keys generated by triggers out of the box.

You can use a custom identity generator described in [Before Insert Trigger and ID generator](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=973262):

```
class Employee {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "trigger_gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "trigger_gen", 
        value = "jpl.hibernate.util.TriggerAssignedIdentityGenerator")
    private int RECORDID; 
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if your entities have non-PK unique field, you can use built-in `select` generator.

**See also:**

- [5.1.2.2. Identifier generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator)

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked for me.I was stuck for quite a long time now.Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to see my custom id generator helped you !